# Loading/Saving from file c++ (serialization?)

Tags: c++

I'm doing home works and our task is to do "Library system"
I got stuck at saving/loading books from file.

```
void Library::save() {
std::ofstream file(fileName);
if (file.is_open()) {
    for (auto &b : books) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        std::stringstream genres;
        for (auto &g : b.getGenres())
            genres << g;

        ss << b.getName() << b.getAutor() << b.getMajor() << genres.str() << b.getBorrowed() << "\n";
        file << ss.str();
    }
    file.close();
}


void Library::load() {
std::streampos size;
char *memblock;

std::ifstream file(fileName, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
if (file.is_open()) {
    size = file.tellg();
    memblock = new char[size];
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    file.read(memblock, size);
    file.close();

    printf(memblock);
    std::cout << sizeof(memblock);


    delete[] memblock;
}
```

}

When I load it is all in row, how do I separte them? or I have done this all wrong?

Comment: "When I load it is all in row" what do you mean?
Please post a sample input and what happens after reading the file

Comment: look at the file using an editor. Is it all one line or separate lines. If all one line, fix your save function. If separate lines fix your display function

Comment: It looks like the code that saves, doesn't separate the items in any way. Better think of some separator. A common convention is to use simple commas; this is then called a *comma-separated file*, or CSV file. Most spreadsheet programs can handle CSV files.

Comment: The input code is horrible and looks wrong-ish. Ditch that.

Comment: You need to show a [MCVE]

Comment: @Paul Götzinger "Who Moved My Cheese?Spencer JohnsonMotivational0" in txt file.

should I use | as separator?

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf Can you help me/tell how to do it correct way?

Comment: Try to make a separate small exploration program that produces the output on `cout`. Then you can more easily see the result.

Comment: You somehow need to distinguish between the different fields. Using a seperator would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, and you didn't include all your code, but what i think you might be asking is how to separate lines in a text file. You can use "\n" to skip to the next line when writing to a file. If this is helpful, please vote it up.